# kafka consume management based on offset-id across different cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have some apache Kafka consumer code which is running and gets user details and processes and update accordingly.

Currently I am using kafka offset to keep track of till what record I processor properly.

whenever my consumers restarts due to any reason(one nodes goes down and other nodes gets data, or consumer restarts etc)   first it sets Kafka offset read from based on the offset it is processed

```
consumer.seek(//get the offset from db);
```

and starts polling

```
consumer.poll()
```

now the problem is due to some different region failure test, the same application will run in other place and will start process the new data.

i.e data base is globally synced but there is no sync between kafka cluster of different region so I get offset which not sequenced for same topic in different region.

Hence I end up with seeking different offset in other region.

whenever fail-over happens, data in first cluster will not be psyched to second cluster, this is okay as per business requirement.

current problem is when a new record comes to second cluster, I should not start with offset set by first cluster application, this can be managed by saving offset along with Kafka clusterID(name) so whenever seek for a offset I can query along with cluster to get region based offset.

is there any better-way to handle this situation ?

Comment: "there is no sync between kafka cluster of different region" ... Could you use MirrorMaker2 to fix that?

Comment: Will mirrormake2 guarantees the offset syncing also? what I got from some documentation is MM2 can guarantee the record syncing but not exact offset synching

Comment: Thats mirrormaker 1, not 2. Refer bullet 3 https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror#mirrormaker-20